# Book/series with winged elven hybrids and a group bringing a child to the north to defeat a great evil

Tags: story-identification, novel

So, I began reading this series years ago and put it down, and now I've been thinking about it and want to see how it ended.

It was a basic Epic. Group needed to destroy evil somewhere off in the world. Must have read it in the early 2000s. The most I remember is based off of the characters.

There was a species of elven hybrids; they were winged, the product of a forced union by an evil magical entity. The elves hated them. Another species (I think they were terromancers), created a mountain kingdom/realm to protect them.

One of the main characters was a wizard prodigy; he'd been babied his entire life and while magically advanced, had a lot of growing up to do.

There was a general who, in order to gain advantage on the battlefield, bonded to (I think) an earth god through a shamanistic pain ceremony.

Another was an unlanded (I think) elf (his kingdom had been destroyed) he was a mercenary.

They were all fighting to get the wizard/child to the north to kill/defeat this great evil who lived in a stronghold on the other side of the world.

Thanks all! And sorry it's so vague. I've been searching the internet for most of the day. Nothing's turned up.

Comment: You missed the two main characters, Crow and Princess Alexis. That may be why it didn't appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are referring to the fantasy trilogy [*The Dragoncrown War Cycle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DragonCrown_War_Cycle), by Michael Stackpole.

Books in the Trilogy

- Fortress Draconis
- When Dragons Rage
- The Grand Crusade

Published from 2000 - 2003. (Technically there are 4 books, but one book, The Dark Glory War is a fairly standalone prequel).

Elements that match:

- Winged Half Elves - The Gyrkyme, shunned by elves as being begotten by rape and crossbreeding of species
- Wizard prodigy - Kerrigan Reese - Raised solely as a magical weapon, with no understanding of, well, anything in the real world
- Bonded earth god - There are a few, but the main one is General Androgans, who because he is half blooded with a shaman race is able to bond to a wyrun/spirit of pain to effect great things. (His uncle/mentor is bonded to earth, IIRC)
- Almost all Elves in the series are unhomed, the main mercenary one is Resolute, companion to Kedyn's Crow.
- Child to save the world - Will, who is purported to be "The Norrington", a child destined to free the elves and save the world from the evil Queen of the North, Chrytienne

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! It's been so long since I've read any of them, I only remembered bits and pieces.