# Book about elves with tattoos associated with magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, elves

The book I'm trying to find I read a few years ago. As far as I can remember, there's an elf who has tattoos somehow attached to his magic. I remember a piece of the book where the other main character, the female, had re-tattooed one for him. Not much to go on, but that's about all I remember.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book/series with winged elven hybrids and a group bringing a child to the north to defeat a great evil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182265/book-series-with-winged-elven-hybrids-and-a-group-bringing-a-child-to-the-north)

Comment: I don't see anything about tattoos in that question or answer... unless "pain ceremony" is the part the other OP remembered. Tattoo wasn't found in a page search on the book page in wikipedia either. it is possible this could be another title. IMO this should be left open until the OP can provide more details or confirm the match.

Comment: @InventPalooza This question has no accepted answer. See [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/21267) about closing story-ident questions.

Comment: @Möoz This is at least a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194894/fantasy-series-with-a-warrior-elf-who-had-magic-tattoos?noredirect=1&lq=1 which is marked as the duplicate that I originally flagged this as.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fantasy series with a warrior elf who had magic tattoos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194894/fantasy-series-with-a-warrior-elf-who-had-magic-tattoos)

Answer (score 5):

Could this be the DragonCrown War Cycle series? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DragonCrown_War_Cycle):

> The DragonCrown War Cycle is a four book fantasy series consisting of a prequel, The Dark Glory War, and three main volumes, Fortress Draconis, When Dragons Rage, and The Grand Crusade. The books were written by Michael A. Stackpole and published by Bantam Spectra, a subsidiary of Randomhouse inc. over the course of 4 years from 2000-2003. The books follow a group of heroes as they struggle to bring to fruition the Norrington Prophecy, so that they can defeat the evil Queen of the north, Chytrine, and save the southern kingdoms from destruction.

[Another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194894/82909) says "there was a warrior elf with magic tattoos that glowed blue".